# Error : java.sql.SQLException: JZ0P1: Unexpected result type

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

My code is simple

```
CallableStatement stmt = Conn.prepareCall ("{call  Reconciliation (?)}");
stmt.setString(date);
PS.executeUpdate();
```

Am using Sybase (Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7.0) and jconnect4 drivers if it is relevant to solution.
My procedure(Reconcliliation) is quite huge so I couldn't post it here but it does some updates to some 1 tables (Recon) after some comparison of data from another 2 tables (Deals1 and Deals2). It do not return any `out` parameters in procedure, it takes only 1 `in` parameter which is date.
When I run java code and run the procedure using callable statement it produces some updates data in table (Recon, count is 500) and the error I get after that is this :

> java.sql.SQLException: JZ0P1: Unexpected result type.
>           at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.updateLoop(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybCallableStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at DBConnection.ExecuteProc(DBConnection.java:88)

Am pretty sure there is no error in my procedure (Reconciliation) because when I run the same procedure in Aqua Data Studio with command `exec Reconciliation '04-Dec-2016'` it doesn't give any error and produces full update in tables (Recon, total count is 800).
There is no error in java as well because it is giving sql exception. If am not wrong there must be some problem in middle i.e jconnect drivers or something else.
Please help me with this, thanks in adv.

Comment: Is there a newer driver or an official one you can try instead?

Comment: Am not sure of a new version, but can you provide any download link to that i can try it out @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: Sorry no.  You may want to look at the files inside Aqua Data Studio to see what driver they use - you may be able to copy a jar file and use that.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I couldn't find any good answers to this question online when I had the same problem.

The big hint came from http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0700/html/prjdbc0700/CHDGJJIG.htm

```
JZ0P1 Unexpected result type.

Description: The database has returned a result that the statement cannot 
return to the application, or that the application is not expecting at this
point. This generally indicates that the application is using JDBC incorrectly
to execute the query or stored procedure. If the JDBC application is connected 
to an Open Server application, it may indicate an error in the Open Server 
application that causes the Open Server to send unexpected sequences of results.
```

The stored procedure is returning tables.  Don't do:

```
PS.executeUpdate();
```

But do this instead:

```
ResultSet rs = callableStatement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

For old jdbc drivers, I´ve noticed that

```
PS.executeUpdate();
```

raises this error while

```
PS.execute();
```

does not